# Quasar Testing unit fail to install because is not compatible with quasar v2.10.1 and it is required <2.0.0

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, quasar

I am tryining to integrate unit testing and I run this commands:

1. `quasar ext add @quasar/testing`
2. `quasar ext add @quasar/testing-unit-jest`

But after I execute the second command, I got this error:

```
Extension(@quasar/testing-unit-jest): is not compatible with quasar v2.10.1. Required version: <2.0.0
```

I am running on Vue version 3.0.0 and quasar 2.6.0

Comment: The solution is given in the error. Use a lower version of the package (check your `package.json`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a beta quasar-testing-jest that supports qv2: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar-testing/releases/tag/unit-jest-v3.0.0-beta.5

There is a migration guide on that link

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).